# Problem with GoogleMobileAds when build IOS game

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode8

I created a Unity game, after that I already installed cocoapods & googlemobileads on the folder that I export to Xcode (Installed success with command). But when I build the project I got this issued.

**Below view the error message.**

[image: Screen Shot]

Seemlike its coming from GoogleMobileAds and specifically from the Google Mobile Reward video. Please anyone can advise how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Set "Enable Modules" to true in Build settings in XCode.